# Wildfly 8.0.0 fails to deploy new project when old project worked

Tags: maven, wildfly

I created a sample application and maven deploys just fine to a local Wildfly 8.0.0 server (by using the command `mvn wildfly:deploy`).  I then created a very similar project with only slight modifications to the classes (changing package names, and adding some SSL implementation), but keeping the pom essentially the same (the only changes I made were to the group and artifact IDs).  When I try to deploy this new application, I get the following exception:

```
13:23:53,309 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."smartgrid-secure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."smartgrid-secure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000075: Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] public org.jboss.resteasy.core.AcceptHeaderByFileSuffixFilter.mediaTypeMappings
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkBeanImplementation(ManagedBean.java:218)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.internalInitialize(AbstractClassBean.java:74)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.internalInitialize(ManagedBean.java:96)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.RIBean.initialize(RIBean.java:65)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$5.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:114)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$5.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:112)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
... 3 more
```

I am also seeing a lot of missing dependency errors.  I am a noobie to Maven and Wildfly, but I was under the impression that the pom defines all the needed dependencies.  If the original project worked, and the poms are nearly identical, shouldn't Maven have no problems deploying my new project?

Here's the pom for the new project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sensorcloud</groupId>
<artifactId>smartgrid-secure</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>smartgrid-secure</name>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
            <configuration>
                <force>true</force>
                <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                <username>wildfly-admin</username>
                <password></password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
     <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0</version>
   </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-MR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-websocket-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketbox-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
      <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.1.CR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-controller-client</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.micromata.jak</groupId>
        <artifactId>JavaAPIforKml</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Any help would be appreciated, since I have been smashing my head against the wall for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the POM was adding a whole bunch of stuff that I thought I needed, but in actuality didn't. I got rid of everything except the `javax.mail`, `org.jboss.logging`, `de.micromata.jak`, and `com.datastax.*`dependencies. I then added a needed (for some reason I don't know) dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId> 
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>  
</dependency>
```

and then everything was cool.